# How to get subtotals using SQL with multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking to produce a report on sales orders and sales quotes that groups and sums to give a subtotal of each quote and order.

It should total "Line Amount" for "Document #'s" (orders/quotes) that are grouped together.

Would also be great to get a grand total as well but not 100% required.

I have tried using `ROLLUP` to produce this but haven't succeeded.

[image: Click here for sample data and desired result]

```
SELECT
  CONVERT (VARCHAR(12),SH.[Order Date],107) AS [Posting Date],
  SH.[Salesperson]            AS [Sales Staff],
  SH.[No_]                AS [Document No],
  SH.[Customer No_]                   AS [Cust. No.],
  SH.[Customer Name]              AS [Customer Name],
  SH.[Country]                AS [Country],
  CONVERT (Decimal(10,0),SL.[Quantity])   AS [Qty.],
  SL.[Unit of Measure]            AS [UOM],
  SL.[No_]                AS [Product No.],
  SL.[Description]            AS [Product Description],
  CONVERT (Decimal(10,2),SL.[Unit Price])     AS [Unit Price],
  SUM (CONVERT (Decimal(10,2),SL.[Line Amount]))    AS [Line Amt.],
  SH.[Currency]                       AS [Currency],
FROM    [Sales Header] SH
JOIN    [Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
GROUP BY    
  SH.[No_], 
  SH.[Salesperson],
  SH.[Order Date],                  
  SH.[Customer No_],
  SH.[Customer Name],
  SH.[Country],
  SH.[Currency],
  SL.[Quantity],                                
  SL.[Unit of Measure],                                             
  SL.[No_],                                                 
  SL.[Description],     
  SH.[Document Type],
  SL.[Unit Price]           
HAVING 
  SH.[Document Type] = '0' OR SH.[Document Type] = '1' AND SL.[Quantity] > '0'
```

Comment: Do you have table structure you can share?

Comment: Usually this kind of subtotals are calculated on the client, in whatever reporting tool you use; not on the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve subtotal lines, you need multiple queries or aggregate on client side. With multiple queries, you can query datastore several times or place initial detail in temp table and then get summaries. Below is querying multiple times. There is a slight risk of data changing in between queries.

```
      -- Line details
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SH.[Order Date], 107) AS [Posting Date]
    ,SH.[Salesperson] AS [Sales Staff]
    ,SH.[No_] AS [Document No]
    ,SH.[Customer No_] AS [Cust. No.]
    ,SH.[Customer Name] AS [Customer Name]
    ,SH.[Country] AS [Country]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 0), SL.[Quantity]) AS [Qty.]
    ,SL.[Unit of Measure] AS [UOM]
    ,SL.[No_] AS [Product No.]
    ,SL.[Description] AS [Product Description]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Unit Price]) AS [Unit Price]
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) AS [Line Amt.]
    ,SH.[Currency] AS [Currency]
    ,'Detail' LineType

FROM [Sales Header] SH
INNER JOIN [Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
WHERE SH.[Document Type] = '0'
    OR SH.[Document Type] = '1'
    AND SL.[Quantity] > '0'

GROUP BY 
    SH.[Order Date]
    ,SH.[Salesperson]
    ,SH.[No_]
    ,SH.[Customer No_]
    ,SH.[Customer Name]
    ,SH.[Country]
    ,SL.[Quantity]
    ,SL.[Unit of Measure]
    ,SL.[No_]
    ,SL.[Description]
    ,SL.[Unit Price]
    ,SH.[Currency]

UNION ALL


  -- Order Summary
  SELECT [Posting Date]
    , [Sales Staff]
    , [Document No]
    , [Cust. No.]
    , [Customer Name]
    , [Country]
    , NULL AS [Qty.] -- not needed is sub total line
    , NULL AS [UOM] -- not needed is sub total line
    , NULL AS [Product No.] -- not needed is sub total line
    , NULL AS [Product Description] -- not needed is sub total line
    , NULL AS [Unit Price] -- not needed is sub total line
    , SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) OVER (PARTITION BY SH.[No_]) AS [Line Amt.] -- TotalAmountByOrder
    , [Currency]
    ,'Order' LineType
  FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SH.[Order Date], 107) AS [Posting Date]
    ,SH.[Salesperson] AS [Sales Staff]
    ,SH.[No_] AS [Document No]
    ,SH.[Customer No_] AS [Cust. No.]
    ,SH.[Customer Name] AS [Customer Name]
    ,SH.[Country] AS [Country]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 0), SL.[Quantity]) AS [Qty.]
    ,SL.[Unit of Measure] AS [UOM]
    ,SL.[No_] AS [Product No.]
    ,SL.[Description] AS [Product Description]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Unit Price]) AS [Unit Price]
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) AS [Line Amt.]
    ,SH.[Currency] AS [Currency]
FROM [Sales Header] SH
INNER JOIN [Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
WHERE SH.[Document Type] = '0'
    OR SH.[Document Type] = '1'
    AND SL.[Quantity] > '0'

GROUP BY 
    SH.[Order Date]
    ,SH.[Salesperson]
    ,SH.[No_]
    ,SH.[Customer No_]
    ,SH.[Customer Name]
    ,SH.[Country]
    ,SL.[Quantity]
    ,SL.[Unit of Measure]
    ,SL.[No_]
    ,SL.[Description]
    ,SL.[Unit Price]
    ,SH.[Currency]
) T


UNION ALL


  -- Grand total
  SELECT NULL AS [Posting Date]
    , NULL AS [Sales Staff]
    , NULL AS [Document No]
    , NULL AS [Cust. No.]
    , NULL AS [Customer Name]
    , NULL AS [Country]
    , NULL AS [Qty.] -- not needed is total line
    , NULL AS [UOM] -- not needed is total line
    , NULL AS [Product No.] -- not needed is total line
    , NULL AS [Product Description] -- not needed is total line
    , NULL AS [Unit Price] -- not needed is total line
    , SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS [Line Amt.] -- TotalAmountAllOrders
    , NULL AS [Currency] -- not needed is total line
    , 'All' LineType
  FROM [Sales Header] SH
    INNER JOIN [Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
    WHERE SH.[Document Type] = '0'
        OR SH.[Document Type] = '1'
        AND SL.[Quantity] > '0'
```

**Initial Response**

It will be nice to see sample data or table structure. Based on what you have, my best guess on what you are trying to achieve is at below.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SH.[Order Date], 107) AS [Posting Date]
    ,SH.[Salesperson] AS [Sales Staff]
    ,SH.[No_] AS [Document No]
    ,SH.[Customer No_] AS [Cust. No.]
    ,SH.[Customer Name] AS [Customer Name]
    ,SH.[Country] AS [Country]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 0), SL.[Quantity]) AS [Qty.]
    ,SL.[Unit of Measure] AS [UOM]
    ,SL.[No_] AS [Product No.]
    ,SL.[Description] AS [Product Description]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Unit Price]) AS [Unit Price]
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) AS [Line Amt.]
    ,SH.[Currency] AS [Currency]

    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) OVER (PARTITION BY SH.[No_]) TotalAmountByOrder
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) OVER (PARTITION BY SH.[Salesperson]) TotalAmountBySalesPerson
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) OVER (PARTITION BY SH.[Customer No_]) TotalAmountByCustomer
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SL.[Line Amount])) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) TotalAmounAllOrders

FROM [Sales Header] SH
INNER JOIN [Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
WHERE SH.[Document Type] = '0'
    OR SH.[Document Type] = '1'
    AND SL.[Quantity] > '0'

GROUP BY 
    SH.[Order Date]
    ,SH.[Salesperson]
    ,SH.[No_]
    ,SH.[Customer No_]
    ,SH.[Customer Name]
    ,SH.[Country]
    ,SL.[Quantity]
    ,SL.[Unit of Measure]
    ,SL.[No_]
    ,SL.[Description]
    ,SL.[Unit Price]
    ,SH.[Currency]
```

1. The having although correct in this situation ideally belongs to the where clause.  Moving it to the where clause, we no longer need it in the grouping and we no longer need to include SH.[Document Type] in group by.
2. Reordered your group by. Did that just to compare all the columns in the select statement to confirm nothing was missing
3. Added a few aggregation columns. Sum for each order, for each salesperson, for each customer and grand total. You can figure out the exact total you need using any of those examples.

Comment: I added a link to some sample data. I tested your method and it works but it provides a total amount for the order on every line. I would prefer to have a subtotal line so the total for the order is only displayed once, if possible.

Comment: @adhocEY, to get a separate line,  you need to do that on the client side. The alternative to to perform multiple queries. One to get detail and one to get summaries. You can then do a union. The alternative to improve accuracy/performance is to copy initial data to temp table then perform subsequent queries on temp table.

Comment: Hi Osa E, Sorry on late response. can you explain what you mean when you say "you need to do that on the client side"?  Do you mean you need to do that using report builder /  SSRS?  Thanks.